# JDeps says module not found when working with module project

Tags: java, java-platform-module-system, jdeps

I'm struggling with `jdeps`. Java 17.

I have a modular app, with a single module and single module-info.java. It works fine.

I'm trying to run `jdeps` in order to find the required JDK modules so I can use it with `jlink`.

When I run this command:

```
jdeps --multi-release 17 --ignore-missing-deps --print-module-deps --class-path 'target/libs/*' target/classes
```

It gives me this exception message:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.module.FindException: Module jakarta.json.bind not found, required by MyModule

The libs directory has all of the dependency jar files copied into it, and target/classes is my code and such. I do, indeed, have a jar with the `jakarta.json.bind` module.

Now, when I remove the module-info.class file from my build, thus making it a "non-modular" project (as far as I can tell, this is the only difference between a modular and non-modular project), I run `jdeps` again.

```
jdeps --multi-release 17 --class-path "target/libs/*" target/classes
```

It lists the `jakarta.json.bind` modules, and shows it resolved (white space elided):

```
my.project  -> jakarta.json.bind  jakarta.json.bind-api-2.0.0.jar
```

In fact, it has no complaints whatsoever. I even added `-R` to make it recursive, and it does not mention any missing modules.

I said "Oh, I should be using module-path instead of class-path":

```
jdeps --multi-release 17 --module-path "target/libs/*" target/classes
```

Same problem. It's complaining about different modules (I've seen it complain about `javafx.graphics` and `javafx.media`). But the problem is the same. The same exception is thrown.

I find it odd that `jdeps` chooses to thrown an exception, rather than just print out that the module is missing.

So, in summary, I have a working modular project. It builds, it executes fine. `jdeps` gives me these exceptions in the use cases above, but when I remove my `module-info.class` file, the `jdeps` gives me all sorts of useful information. Just not when my project is a module.

Why does `jdeps` not work on my module project?